# Scan documents into a Web Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, image-scanner

I need to scan documents inside a web application (initially. NET).

Is there a free alternative to detect the scanner connected to the client machine and scan the image directly to the browser?

I know WingScan of Atalasoft does something similar, but is a relatively new and expensive tool.

Thoughts?

Comment: You mean ASP.NET?  There is a com tool WIA but I don't think you can use that from a browser.

Comment: Try to search "using TWAIN" from JavaScript or Silverlight. As I remember there are should be some ways to do this.

Comment: I dont think there is free SDK for interacting with scanners from browsers. You may need to build an ActiveX/a browser plugin from scratch. Reading the TWAIN specification is a good start. Or, consider  this commercial product, [Dynamic Web TWAIN](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/WebTWAIN_Overview.aspx). It is very mature and reasonably charged.